# Recognize telnet protocol with Scapy python

Tags: python, telnet, scapy

I am reading a Pcap file with Scapy. How can I recognize if, in this pcap file, there is a packet that uses the Telnet protocol?

I see that Scapy can write 'telnet' into dport/sport only if 1 of those ports is 23, but if I am using another port for Telnet, how do I recognize this with Scapy?

Comment: Realistically, you can't.  Telnet is indistinguishable from other TCP protocols.

Comment: telnet isnt a protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@TimRoberts stated in the comments that "Telnet is indistinguishable from other TCP protocols." This is true to some extent, because all TCP packets use the same structure, which is outlined in multiple Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) Request for Comments (RFC) documents:

- [RFC 791 - Internet Protocol (IP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc791)
- [RFC 793 - Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793)

Here is the structure of a TCP packet.

[image]

Common application protocols such as Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), File Transfer Protocol (FTP) and Telnet all use this structure.

Concerning the application protocol Telnet. As you already know the official port assignment for the telnet protocol is port 23.  Most vendors adhere to this port standard, which is why "Scapy can write 'telnet' into dport/sport only if 1 of those ports is 23."

This is the TCP layer from a Telnet session using port 23:

```
Layer TCP:
    Source Port: 1254
    Destination Port: 23
    Stream index: 0
    TCP Segment Len: 0
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence number (raw): 72603759
    Next sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    1010 .... = Header Length: 40 bytes (10)
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
    .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
    Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 23
    Connection establish request (SYN): server port 23
    Severity level: Chat
    Group: Sequence
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    TCP Flags: \xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7S\xc2\xb7
    Window size value: 32120
    Calculated window size: 32120
    Checksum: 0x5d40 [unverified]
    Checksum Status: Unverified
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (20 bytes), Maximum segment size, SACK permitted, Timestamps, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale
    TCP Option - Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
    Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
    Length: 4
    MSS Value: 1460
    TCP Option - SACK permitted
    TCP Option - Timestamps: TSval 1444389, TSecr 0
    Timestamp value: 1444389
    Timestamp echo reply: 0
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - Window scale: 0 (multiply by 1)
    Shift count: 0
    Multiplier: 1
    Timestamps
    Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Kind: SACK Permitted (4)
    Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Window Scale (3)
    Length: 2
    Length: 10
    Length: 3
```

This is the TCP layer from a Telnet session using port 3005:

```
Layer TCP:
    Source Port: 52187
    Destination Port: 3005
    Stream index: 0
    TCP Segment Len: 0
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence number (raw): 1355255000
    Next sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    1011 .... = Header Length: 44 bytes (11)
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
    .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
    Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 3005
    Connection establish request (SYN): server port 3005
    Severity level: Chat
    Group: Sequence
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    TCP Flags: \xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7S\xc2\xb7
    Window size value: 65535
    Calculated window size: 65535
    Checksum: 0x0afb [unverified]
    Checksum Status: Unverified
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (24 bytes), Maximum segment size, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale, No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps, SACK permitted, End of Option List (EOL)
    TCP Option - Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
    Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
    Length: 4
    MSS Value: 1460
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - Window scale: 6 (multiply by 64)
    Shift count: 6
    Multiplier: 64
    TCP Option - Timestamps: TSval 3609205717, TSecr 0
    Timestamp value: 3609205717
    Timestamp echo reply: 0
    TCP Option - SACK permitted
    TCP Option - End of Option List (EOL)
    Timestamps
    Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Window Scale (3)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
    Kind: SACK Permitted (4)
    Kind: End of Option List (0)
    Length: 3
    Length: 10
    Length: 2
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
```

This is the TCP layer from a FTP session using port 21:

```
Layer TCP:
    Source Port: 35974
    Destination Port: 21
    Stream index: 0
    TCP Segment Len: 0
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence number (raw): 29473206
    Next sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    1010 .... = Header Length: 40 bytes (10)
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
    .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
    Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 21
    Connection establish request (SYN): server port 21
    Severity level: Chat
    Group: Sequence
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    TCP Flags: \xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7S\xc2\xb7
    Window size value: 32648
    Calculated window size: 32648
    Checksum: 0x8fda [unverified]
    Checksum Status: Unverified
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (20 bytes), Maximum segment size, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale, No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
    TCP Option - Maximum segment size: 1380 bytes
    Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
    Length: 4
    MSS Value: 1380
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - Window scale: 0 (multiply by 1)
    Shift count: 0
    Multiplier: 1
    TCP Option - Timestamps: TSval 1657560000, TSecr 0
    Timestamp value: 1657560000
    Timestamp echo reply: 0
    Timestamps
    Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Window Scale (3)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
    Length: 3
    Length: 10
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
```

This is the TCP layer from a SSH session using port 22:

```
Layer TCP:
    Source Port: 57732
    Destination Port: 22
    Stream index: 0
    TCP Segment Len: 0
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence number (raw): 71043058
    Next sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    1011 .... = Header Length: 44 bytes (11)
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
    .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
    Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 22
    Connection establish request (SYN): server port 22
    Severity level: Chat
    Group: Sequence
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    TCP Flags: \xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb7S\xc2\xb7
    Window size value: 65535
    Calculated window size: 65535
    Checksum: 0xd079 [unverified]
    Checksum Status: Unverified
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (24 bytes), Maximum segment size, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale, No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps, SACK permitted, End of Option List (EOL)
    TCP Option - Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
    Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
    Length: 4
    MSS Value: 1460
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - Window scale: 6 (multiply by 64)
    Shift count: 6
    Multiplier: 64
    TCP Option - Timestamps: TSval 1452973307, TSecr 0
    Timestamp value: 1452973307
    Timestamp echo reply: 0
    TCP Option - SACK permitted
    TCP Option - End of Option List (EOL)
    Timestamps
    Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Window Scale (3)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: No-Operation (1)
    Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
    Kind: SACK Permitted (4)
    Kind: End of Option List (0)
    Length: 3
    Length: 10
    Length: 2
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
```

As previously stated these TCP layers are almost indistinguishable.  So trying to use the TCP layer alone would be hard to determine a Telnet session over a port other than port 23.  So trying to use Scapy to identify these sessions without doing a more in-depth packet analysis would be extremely hard.

You could potential analyze the data layer of a TCP packet to determine if a connection is or isn't a Telnet session.  This again requires substantial effort unless you have done some level of traffic analysis.

Using the Python module pyshark you extract content from the Data layer.

Telnet session over port 23:

```
import pyshark

# the pcap is a Telnet session over port 23
capture = pyshark.FileCapture('telnet-raw.pcap')
for packet in capture:
    if hasattr(packet, 'tcp'):
        layers = packet.layers
        #      0            1           2             3
        # [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
        if len(layers) > 3:
            payload = packet.tcp.payload
```

The payload output is in hex

```
truncated...
ff:fb:01:ff:fa:21:02:ff:f0:ff:fc:01

ff:fd:01:ff:fe:01

ff:fa:22:03:05:80:00:11:80:00:12:80:00:ff:f0

0d:0a:4f:70:65:6e:42:53:44:2f:69:33:38:36:20:28:6f:6f:66:29:20:28:74:74:79:70:31:29:0d:0a:0d:0a

6c:6f:67:69:6e:3a:20

ff:fc:22:ff:fd:01
truncated...
```

The 4th and 5th hex strings in the output are an important piece to deciphering what type of TCP connection might be occurring.

```
import binascii

hex_data = '0d:0a:4f:70:65:6e:42:53:44:2f:69:33:38:36:20:28:6f:6f:66:29:20:28:74:74:79:70:31:29:0d:0a:0d:0a6c:6f:67:69:6e:3a:20 '
hex_string = ' '.join(hex_data.split('0d:0a')).replace(':', '')
hex_list = hex_string.split()
for item in hex_list:
    decoded_string = binascii.unhexlify(item)
    print(decoded_string)
    # output 
    b'OpenBSD/i386 (oof) (ttyp1)'
    b'login: '
```

After decoding the hex we can see that authentication is occurring over port 23.

Telnet session over port 3005:

```
import pyshark

# the pcap is a Telnet session over port 3005
capture = pyshark.FileCapture('telnet-pcap-1.pcapng')
for packet in capture:
    if hasattr(packet, 'tcp'):
        layers = packet.layers
        #      0            1           2             3
        # [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
        if len(layers) > 3:
            payload = packet.tcp.payload
```

The payload output is in hex

```
ff:fb:01:ff:fb:03:ff:fd:18:ff:fd:1f

ff:fd:01:ff:fd:03:ff:fb:18:ff:fb:1f:ff:fa:1f:00:97:00:2f:ff:f0

0d:0a:55:73:65:72:20:41:63:63:65:73:73:20:56:65:72:69:66:69:63:61:74:69:6f:6e:0d:0a:0d:0a:55:73:65:72:6e:61:6d:65:3a:20

ff:fa:18:01:ff:f0

ff:fa:18:00:58:54:45:52:4d:2d:32:35:36:43:4f:4c:4f:52:ff:f0
truncated...
```

The 3rd hex string in the output is an important piece to deciphering what type of TCP connection might be occurring.

```
import binascii

hex_data = '0d:0a:55:73:65:72:20:41:63:63:65:73:73:20:56:65:72:69:66:69:63:61:74:69:6f:6e:0d:0a:0d:0a:55:73:65:72:6e:61:6d:65:3a:20'

# removing line breaks from the hex string
hex_string = ' '.join(hex_data.split('0d:0a')).replace(':', '')
hex_list = hex_string.split()
for item in hex_list:
    decoded_string = binascii.unhexlify(item)
    print(decoded_string)
    # output 
    b'User Access Verification'
    b'Username: '
```

After decoding the hex we can see that some type of authentication is occurring over port 3005.  Additional analysis would be required to determine if this session is a Telnet session or some other session.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```py
for pkt in PcapReader('your_file.pcap'):
    # you can try printing summary to see the packet
    print(pkt.summary())
    # should print something like 
    # IP / TCP 10.1.99.25:ftp_data > 10.1.99.2:telnet S

    pkt_src = pkt[IP].src
    pky_type = pkt[IP].type
    pkt_payload = pkt[TCP].payload
    if [...]
```

you could print the pkt dictionary to see under which key the `telnet` string could be falling into and do some pattern matching

*I saw the recommendation to do directly PcapReader as not to take memory with rdpcap in another stackoverflow answer but I lost the link*